# Runtime Foreign Key vs Integerfield

Tags: python, django, model

I have a problem. I already have two solution for my problem, but i was wondering which of those is the faster solution.
I guess that the second solution is not only more convienient- to use but also faster, but i want to be sure, so thats the reason why im asking.
My problem is i want to group multiple rows together. The group won't hold any meta data. So im only interested in runtime.

On the one hand i can use a Integer field and filter it later on when i need to get all entries that belong to the group. I guess runtime of O(n).

```
class SingleEntries(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    group = models.IntegerField(null=True)


def find_all_group_members(id):
    return SingleEntries.objects.filter(group=id)
```

The second solution and probably the more practicle way would be to create a foreign key to another model only using the pk there.
Then i can use the reverse relation to find all the entries that belong to the group.

```
class Group(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class SingleEntries(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

def find_all_group_members(id):
    return Group.objects.get(id=id).singleentries_set.all()
```

Comment: I am not sure what exactly the problem you have is, could you be more specific and perhaps add some code snippets with what you've tried (or what you could do)?

Comment: Just go for the foreign key relationship, there's probably not much performance difference but there are much bigger practical benefits

Comment: The first is more efficient, since this will use *one* query, whereas the latter will first fetch the `Group`, and then another one for the `SingleEntries`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is more efficient, since this will use *one* query, whereas the latter will first fetch the `Group`, and then another one for the `SingleEntries`.

Indeed, if you work with:

```
SingleEntries.objects.filter(group=id)
```

this will make a simple query:

```
SELECT appname_singleentries.*
FROM appname_singleentries
WHERE appname_singleentries.group_id = id
```

It thus does *not* first fetch the `Group` into memory.

The latter will however make *two* queries. Indeed, it will first make a query to retrieve the `Group`, and then it will make a query like the one above to fetch the `SingleEntries`.

The two are also semantically not entirely the same: if there is no such group, then the former will return an *empty* `QuerySet`, whereas the latter will raise a `Group.DoesNotExists` exception.

But you can model this with:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    pass

class SingleEntries(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)


def find_all_group_members(id):
    return SingleEntries.objects.filter(group_id=id)
```

So you can use a `Group` model *without* having to retrieve the `Group` first.

Comment: Do you know if the reverse Foreign key is stored in the Group or is it doing a Query on the SingleEntries? 
Because if the index is stored and say we have the special case of (m = number of entries in Group, n = number of entries in SingleEntries, c = max. number of ForeignKeys to one Group ) n>>m or n>>>m. So getting the entry in m would be way faster than in n -> O(n)>>O(m), And retrieving the entries from the indexes would be something like O(log(n)). Which could mean that when n>(m+log(n)) the second one might be faster even though it does make 2 queries. Please correct me if im mistaken.

Comment: @Mole: it does not store the reversed foreign key no. But the database will make an index for `ForeignKey`s, so normally it can obtain the items from a B-Tree that will then take at most *O(log(n))* to obtain the items, and *O(m)* to retrieve the items from the disk.

Answer (score 0):

If the groups are static in nature, that means if you don't see more groups coming to your system, you can use [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) in Django.

Define choices as below

```
class GroupType(models.IntegerChoices):
    GROUP_0 = 0, "Group 0 name"
    GROUP_1 = 1, "Group 1 name"
    GROUP_2 = 2, "Group 2 name"
```

And use it as choices field in the `SingleEntries` model as below

```
class SingleEntries(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    group = models.IntegerField(choices=GroupChoices.choices, default=<set default here>)
```

If the groups are dynamic, meaning users can create groups whenever they want, in that case, go with your second approach of having another model for group.